# What vegetable for sauteed zucchini could I use instead of tomatoes?

Tags: substitutions, tomatoes, zucchini

I like to fry or sautee onions, garlic, chilis, spices (for flavor) and zucchini (the main ingredient); then stir them in a can of chopped tomatoes and simmer for a few minutes. The tomatoes are a way to add a sauce with some thickness that brings all the ingredients together. I want to get close to the texture and consistency, but I'm looking for something else so the dish does not always taste the same.

Is there another vegetable or fruit I could use instead of the tomatoes?

Comment: today at lunch I used onions and a little ground beef in my sauteed zucchini. That time of year.

Comment: Does it have to be a vegetable? Why not some other sauce? Why not zucchini and a protein?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't have to be a vegetable. But, something with the same consistency, somewhere between a sauce and a soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cottage cheese will keep it consistent and match very well with the zucchini & spices.

Comment: Interesting -- for the cottage cheese, how long does it have to cook? Does it have to simmer, or just warm it a bit? (I have no experience cooking with cottage cheese)

Answer (score 1):

You could use coconut milk and curry-type flavorings (e.g. coriander, cumin, turmeric, galangal, ginger, lemongrass, any type of chili pepper, cilantro), for a very different taste with a somewhat similar texture.

Answer (score 0):

Diced eggplant (aubergine) with some coriander and cumin cooked with the zucchini would also give a very thick sauce consistency.  I would cook the eggplant first, until it is quite 'mushy', so as not to overcook the zucchini.  If you needed to thin the sauce you could add some stock or a little tomato paste and water.

Top it with a big blob of natural yoghurt at the end if you like that type of flavour.

Answer (score 0):

I like to cook mushrooms with my onions, garlic, and zucchini.  I prefer cremini (baby bellas), and I salt them so that they give up a lot of water, which can make things a bit sauc-y.  And, of course, you can always mix up the spices.